# Assign application pool to website in iis7 programmatically

Tags: c#, iis-7

I'm using the following method to create application pool and assign it to web site.

This is code for application pool creation:

```
WebSiteName = some website name which existed.
```

I see that all values are get where they should be in debug mode

```
 private void ConfiugreAppPoolIIS7(targetMachine)
    {
        var mgr =  ServerManager.OpenRemote(targetMachine);

        if (AppPoolProp.ContainsKey("SomeTestAppPool"))
        {
            string reqAppPool = AppPoolProp["SomeTestAppPool"];

            if (!mgr.ApplicationPools.Any(pool => pool.Name == reqAppPool))
            {
                ApplicationPool myApp = mgr.ApplicationPools.Add(reqAppPool);
                myApp.AutoStart = true;
                myApp.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Classic;
                myApp.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "V4.0";
                myApp.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.NetworkService;
                myApp.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;

                mgr.CommitChanges();

                foreach (Site site in mgr.Sites)
                {
                   if(site.Name == WebSiteName)
                   {
                       site.Stop();
                       site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = myApp.Name;
                       site.Start();
                       mgr.CommitChanges();
                   }

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

The result is, I see the Aplication pool created successfuly, and the Website created as well, but, I see in the advanced settings of my web site the *default* appplication pool is assigned.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been fixed by fixing reference to right Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll

Cause of this server manage connected to express iis instead of my local iis.